# How can I create a collapsible menu with nested menu items?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, submenu

When clicking on menu level 1, it should expand, and all siblings should be closed. The same should happen at all level of menu items while clicking.

Example: Click on menu level 3, and menu items at level 4 should *not* display, and all menu items at level 3 *should* display.

How can I achieve this? Here's what I have so far:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s125paua/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
 <ul class="nav level-1">
  <li class="has-submenu">
     <a href="#">Menu Level1</a>
    <ul class="level-2">
        <li class="has-submenu">
           <a href="#">Menu-Level2</a>
           <ul class="level-3">
              <li class="has-submenu">
                 <a href="#">Menu Level3</a>
                 <ul class="level-4">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="has-submenu">
                 <a href="#">Menu-Level3</a>
                 <ul class="level-3">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
           <a href="#">Menu-Level2</a>
           <ul class="level-3">
              <li><a href="#">Menu-Level3</a></li>
              <li class="has-submenu">
                 <a href="#">Menu-Level3</a>
                 <ul class="level-4">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-submenu">
     <a href="#">Menu Level1 </a>
     <ul class="level-2">
        <li class="has-submenu">
           <a href="#">Menu-Level2</a>
           <ul class="level-3">
              <li class="has-submenu">
                 <a href="#">Menu Level3</a>
                 <ul class="level-4">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="has-submenu">
                 <a href="#">Menu-Level3</a>
                 <ul class="level-3">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
           <a href="#">Menu-Level2</a>
           <ul class="level-3">
              <li><a href="#">Menu-Level3</a></li>
              <li class="has-submenu">
                 <a href="#">Menu-Level3</a>
                 <ul class="level-4">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-submenu">
     <a href="#">Menu Level1</a>
     <ul class="level-2">
        <li class="has-submenu">
           <a href="#">Menu-Level2</a>
           <ul class="level-3">
              <li class="has-submenu">
                 <a href="#">Menu Level3</a>
                 <ul class="level-4">
                    <li class="end"><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                    <li class="end"><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="has-submenu">
                 <a href="#">Menu-Level3</a>
                 <ul class="level-3">
                    <li class="end"><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                    <li class="end"><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
           <a href="#">Menu-Level2</a>
           <ul class="level-3">
              <li><a href="#">Menu-Level3</a></li>
              <li class="has-submenu">
                 <a href="#">Menu-Level3</a>
                 <ul class="level-4">
                    <li class="end"><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                    <li class="end"><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    display:block;
    background:#aaa;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
}
li li {
    display:none;
}
.has-submenu > a:after {
    content:' + ';
}
.has-submenu .nav-open > a:after {
    content:' - ';
}
li li a {
    padding-left:40px;
    background:#888;
}
li li li a {
    padding-left:80px;
    background:#333;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.has-submenu > a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('nav-open').find('> ul > li').slideToggle();
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('> ul > li').slideUp();
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('nav-open');
});
```

Only red highlighted part should be shown if we click on menu level 4:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

These updates will exhibit the behavior that you're looking for.

Add a CSS class called `hidden`:

```
.hidden {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Replace your JavaScript line 4 with:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().toggleClass('hidden').find('> ul > li').slideUp();
```

This will not close/open subnavs when closing a parent nav, but that behavior wasn't mentioned in your question.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/t3jb04L1/3/